# site shows blank screen on IE but works fine in firefox or chrome

Tags: php, internet-explorer, yii

we have developed website  http://www.2vin.com using yii
the site works fine in Firefox and chrome but shows white screen in IE.
we have fixed some of the html errors but it still shows blank screen in yii
site name:  http://www.2vin.com
technology used:  yii in php

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the `<! [endif]-->` in the `head`. Remove the space, changing it to `<![endif]-->`.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up Developers tool (F12) and if you see "inline style{display:none;}"

add a css style in your css file...

```
body{display: block !important;}
```

Answer (score -2):

I've had this issue with IE 9.

The way I resolved this on several machines was by removing the font "Helvetica".

Hope this helps.

J